# Making jQuery Popbox visible outside of its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Using the jQuery popbox library (http://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/index.html) I encountered the following problem:

I have a huge div which has it's overflow set to auto. It is actually a tournament grid displaying a lot of matches to be played. Each match (separate divs) has a small info icon and upon clicking, I'm using the Popbox to display additional information in the window that comes up.

This is all working correctly, however, whenever I press the info icon on a div that's close to the bottom side or the left side of the parent div which has it's overflow set to auto, part of the popbox window is not visible as it ends up outside of the parent div. I'm looking for a user-friendly way to solve this issues.

Setting the parent's div overflow to visible is not an option as I need the scroll bars to appear if it gets too large. It would be nice though if I could make the Popbox window go outside of the parent div and be completely visible.

The other idea that I can think of right now is to set special classes to the info icons close to the edges and adjust the popbox window to the right/top so it is visible in the parent div regardless of its overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use some special classes and make the popover "pop" on top/right.

You can see an example here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

If you want to use Bootstrap you can make a custom build here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=6493526

Popover css+js is only additional ~ 10k min+gzip

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to find a shortcut but finally I ended up coding something similar to bootstrap directly into the Popbox library. It took some time but at least it gives me full control to do whatever I like.